# iterator got by applying begin() on getter method doesn't allow to access to first elements of pointed list

Tags: c++, pointers, object, iterator

I have a object's pointer `*myObject` with a getter method:

```
vector<string> getList();
```

When I create my iterator to run throught my list variable returned by getList() like this:

```
vector<string>::const_iterator it = myObject->getList().begin();
```

and I display it:

```
cout << *it << endl;
```

It displays me nothing (certainly an empty string).
It's similar for `it+1`, `it+2`, `it+3`, `it+4`, but from `it+5` it displays the right element

Whereas, when I rewrite the code like this:

```
vector<string> myList = myObject.getList();
vector<string>::const_iterator it = myList.begin();
cout << *it << endl;
```

Everything works.

Could you help me to understand this problem please?

Thank you.

Comment: `vector<string> getList();` returns a temporary, long gone by the time you dereference that iterator in your first example. the second makes a copy of that list, then iterates *that*. If the list is in your object and you don't want people to muck with it, let *them* make the call on whether to copy it or not and just return a const reference rather than a copy. If it is on-demand-generated in the `getList()` member, you have no other choice than to do your second snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
vector<string>::const_iterator it = myObject->getList().begin();
```

At the end of the line, the iterator `it` is invalid, because the `vector<string>` returned by `getList()` is a temporary value.

However, when you store the `vector<string>` in a local variable, with

```
vector<string> myList = myObject.getList();
```

Then, the iterator remains valid, as long as `myList` is not destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

In the frist case the code has undefined behaviour because the temporary object of type `std::vector<std::string>` returned by function `myObject.getList()` will be deleted at the end pf executing the statement. So the iterator will be invalid.

Apart from the valid code in the second example you could also write

```
const vector<string> &myList = myObject.getList();
vector<string>::const_iterator it = myList.begin();
cout << *it << endl;
```

that is you could use a constant reference to the temporary object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are returning a copy of vector, it would go out of scope and out of existance, thus be invalid.

What you want to do is return a const reference to your list.

```
const vector<string>& getList();
```